# Make Modal | Popup - Re Appear If The Content Is Changed

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm a little stuck, I have developed a custom Wordpress Theme with an OPTIONS PAGE where the client can update the headline and body copy of a **pop up / modal**.

I've used ACF to collect this data, for the FOOTER.PHP template file. Where i've added the html mark up.

And my Javascript for the modal is in my .js file enqueued by my FUNCTIONS.php (see the code below).

So far... I've managed to get the modal to **window.onload** (Open) and **onclick** (close) for a set period of time (using **localStorage**). Currently 20 000ms for testing purpose, but I will increase this to 3-4 hours after testing is complete.

So far - all good and everything is working.

However the client would also like the modal to re-appear straight after they alter the text in the Wordpress Database. (eg. If the carpark was full - the modal would pop up to alert clients immediately - even if they'd recently closed the modal within the localStorage time allowance).

So I need a way for the browser to see that the HEADLINE or PARAGRAPH TEXT has changed and alter/reset the localStorage.

I am trying to add a MutationObserver, to handle this, but I am getting a little lost doing so. Is this the best approach and can anybody help please.

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Options Page Variables
$headline = get_field( 'modal_headline', 'options' );
$copy = get_field( 'modal_copy', 'options' );

if ( $headline && $copy ): { ?>
    <!-- Overlay -->
    <div class="modal-overlay" id="modalOverlay">
        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="modal">
            <!-- Headline -->
            <div class="modal-headline-wrapper">
                <h2><?php echo $headline; ?></h2>
            </div>
            <!-- Message -->
            <div class="modal-paragraph-wrapper">
                <p>Hello text <?php echo $copy; ?></p>
            </div>
            <!-- Close Modal -->
            <div class="modal-button-wrapper">
                <button class="centered-button" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php } endif; ?>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
    animation: animated-modal-in 0.35s forwards;
}
.modal {
    @include flex-center();
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 25vh;
    max-width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 50px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: animated-modal-in 0.75s forwards;
}
```

**JS**

```
// To Open The Modal
function openModal() {
    document.getElementById('modalOverlay').style.display = 'flex';
}

// To Close The Modal
function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById('modalOverlay').style.display = 'none';
    // Store The Current Timestamp In LocalStorage When The Modal Closes
    var closedTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
    localStorage.setItem('modalClosedTimestamp', closedTimestamp);
}

// Check If The Modal Should Be Displayed On Page Load
window.onload = function () {
    // Retrieve The Stored Timestamp | When The Modal Was Closed
    var closedTimestamp = localStorage.getItem('modalClosedTimestamp');
    // If The Modal Hasn't Been Closed | Or It Has Been More Than Set Time
    if (!closedTimestamp || new Date().getTime() - closedTimestamp > 20000) {
        openModal();
    }
};
```

Comment: Store the text of the modal that you _have_ shown, in localstorage as well - so that on the next page load, you can compare the current modal text with that previous one ...?